# Automatically rename multiple files from multiple subfolders through windows cmd

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I am using the following script through windows cmd in automatically copying multiple files located/sourced from multiple subdirectories to a single directory:

```
cd /d "C:\example files\various\raw files"

for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "C:\example files\conso"
```

I put \y at the end of the script if I want to ovewrite duplicate files.

However, my dilemma is I want to **not** overwrite those files, instead automatically renaming them.

Is there any other command in the windows cmd that would try to copy those files and try to rename them if there are duplicates found?

Comment: You may adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5251790/5494004) to your needs

Comment: Hi @SalvoF,

None of those scripts worked for me. It is a kind of complicated. By the way, I'm only a beginner in terms of cmd and scripting.

Is there any other way aside from those suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file. I'm using `cp` command's backup feature. Program can be found under the `\usr\local\wbin` folder of [this zipped file](http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/unxutils/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip) (UnxUtils project). Extract the executable in any folder in your `%PATH%`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set VERSION_CONTROL variable, read by `cp' *nix command
set VERSION_CONTROL=t

rem Define origin and destination folders
set "_orig=C:\example files\various\raw files"
set "_dest=C:\example files\conso"

for /r "%_orig%" %%F in (*.*) do cp -b "%%F" "%_dest%"
for %%N in ("%_dest%\*.*") do (
    set _ext=%%~xN
    if "!_ext:~-1!" == "~" (
       set "_name=%%~nN"
       ren "%%N" "!_name:~0,-4!(!_ext:~-2,1!)!_name:~-4,4!"
    )
)
```

Comment: 1) I don't make any check on what's already in destination folder 2) Having more than 10 identical file names is not managed (that's unlikely I hope) 3) File names containing `!` cause trouble

Comment: Hi @SalvoF, thanks for taking the time. I'll find a way to make your suggestion work. I have a hard time understanding programming languages :) I'm a financial auditor and I don't have much knowledge in IT programming.

Comment: NP. I'm no pro either... but if you face difficulties try to ask. On a note, when I wrote "10 identical file names" I meant **per file** of course, there's no limit on processable files

Comment: Okay. Ill try to make it work.